# Julia: Using the Underscore as a Digit Separator in BigFloat and BigInt

Tags: julia

According to the Julia 1.0.0 [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Floating-Point-Numbers-1):

> The underscore _ can be used as digit separator:

```
julia> 10_000, 0.000_000_005, 0xdead_beef, 0b1011_0010
(10000, 5.0e-9, 0xdeadbeef, 0xb2)
```

However, in the Julia 1.0.0 REPL I get this:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.0.0"

# Underscore does not work work on right side of decimal in BigFloat.
julia> big"3.141_592"
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid number format 3.141_592 for BigInt or BigFloat

 # Underscore does not work on left side of decimal in BigFloat.
julia> big"123_456.7898"
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid number format 123_456.7898 for BigInt or BigFloat

# Underscore works for BigInt in example below:
julia> big"123_456_789"
123456789
julia> typeof(ans)
BigInt
```

Apparently, the underscore can be used in `BigInt`, but not `BigFloat`.

Is this by design or has underscore use for `BigFloat` simply not been implemented yet?

Comment: I think this is just an omission. You should probably file an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/julialang/julia

Comment: @FengyangWang Okay, thanks for tip.  I did.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now posted and discussed on the Julia GitHub Issues site [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29329#issuecomment-424033033).